# Indexing new object with Django & Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-signals, elasticsearch-dsl

I am having trouble getting django to automatically index newly created objects.

I have used `groupby` to create some custom data.

Every time a new model is created, it should index it.

It **does** index the "title" value, but the "tag" value is not there.

So, I created a manual function "manual_index". When I run that, the "tag" value **does** get added to the index. However this process has to be manually triggered.

How can I get the "tag" value to save every time a new object is created?

I'm using elasticsearch_dsl

## Search.py

```
class TaskIndex(DocType):
    title = String()
    class Meta:
        index = 'task-index'

def manual_index():
    TaskIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Task.objects.all().iterator()))
```

## Models.py

```
from itertools import groupby

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField("Tag level", null=True, blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

    def get_grouped_tags(self):
        tag = self.tag.order_by('taglevel')
        grouped_tags = {
            tag_level: [
                { 'name': tag_of_level.name, 'taglevel': tag_of_level.taglevel, }
                for tag_of_level in tags_of_level
            ] for tag_level, tags_of_level
            in groupby(tag, lambda tag: tag.taglevel)
        }
        return grouped_tags

    def indexing(self):
        obj = TaskIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            title=self.title,
            tag=self.get_grouped_tags()
        obj.save()
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several issues here, first of all you are saving everything twice - once inside `indexing` (by calling `.save()`) and then in `manual_index`.

The code in `manual_index` is way more efficient and definitely should be around for reindexing the whole dataset. For individual model creation you can just use the `indexing` method almost as is and use django's `signal` framework. Just modify the `indexing` method to return the `TaskIndex` object (without calling `.save()` on it!) and add the equivalent of the following code into your `models.py`: 
https://github.com/HonzaKral/es-django-example/blob/master/qa/models.py#L128-L137

In your code you will just use `indexing` instead of mine `to_search`.

Hope this helps,
Honza

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked your comment about the `tag` object. The issue there is that, on Django side, the `indexing` is triggered before the many to many data is saved. There are several ways around that, safest is to also use the `m2m_changed` signal - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#m2m-changed